# What gear and level based stats are normalized in Destiny Crucible Multiplayer?

Tags: destiny

I've seen mentioned in a few places that some level based stats are normalized in PvP multiplier in Destiny.  Damage for weapons being the one I've heard most consistently.  Can anyone give me a run down of what gear and player stats are balanced for Crucible play?

Do any of these abilities(including but not limited to) carry over into Crucible matches?

- Damage upgrades for uncommon or rare guns
- Any other weapon upgrades like hair triggers or boosted accuracy
- Defense stats from all my armor
- Armor based ammo and reload speed bonuses

Basically, what does high level abilities, armor, and weapons do for you in a Crucible match?

Comment: You can still use unlocked abilities and I believe gun mods(new scopes, faster ADS, not sure about things like second half of mag does higher damage).  It seems that damage and armor are normalized such that no one really has an advantage over another in terms of how long it takes to shoot someone down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What doesn't carry over (becomes a normalized amount)

- Base defense
- Base weapon attack

What does carry over

- Weapon progression (including damage bonuses)
- Armor progression (Including Defense bonuses)
- Abilities
- Character progression (stat upgrades)

This means that even though they are on relatively equal starting ground. A Level 20+ *will* have an advantage over a level 5, but not so much that the low level doesn't stand a chance.

Comment: This also means that a low level weapon that handles well and has nice upgrades can still be really really good in PvP even if it's too low level for you in PvE.

Comment: Generally yes @Eben, but higher level weapons have more things to upgrade on them, most low levels have their special ability (most of the time just one), and a single damage upgrade. Level 20 gear has much more potential

Comment: Very true as well. Just wanted to point out that a level 10 blue weapon _might_ be preferable in PvP to a level 20 green. But that's largely going to be dependent on play style and luck in drops as well.

Comment: Good point, I'm currently using a rare level 12 Shingen-E for PvP and then the highest damage for PvE.  Has nice control and quite a few upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

The video below tests and compares 3 auto rifles proving that attack does not effect damage but impact definitely does.

Answer (score 0):

Defense and attack bonuses on weapons and armor *do not* carry over. Attack and defense are at base stats.

Weapon abilities and armor abilities will transfer over but not the damage bonuses or armour bonuses.

Answer (score 0):

Damage bonuses for weapons DO carry over. For example, in the video I posted above one of the rifles used was a Shingen that had a not yet unlocked upgrade that increased damage for the second half of the magazine. The weapon was doing 16 normal damage and 24 critical damage, after upgrading the weapon it did 18 normal damage and 25 critical damage.

Comment: If you are trying to reply to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/183834/30879) please comment, if you are trying to improve your previous answer please use [this link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/184092/edit) to edit this. keep in mind this isn't a forum as such unless your second answer differs greatly to your previous one you should not be posting a second